# Ubuntu 21.10 "Show applications" does not list apps in dock

Tags: gnome, 21.10, appmenu

I recently installed Ubuntu and noticed a *possibly purposeful* behavior.

If I add "Chrome" (just as an example) to favorites (which pins it to dock), clicking "Show Applications" button does not list Chrome as one of the apps.

If I remove Chrome from favorites, it turns back to "Show Applications" menu. But I like it in dock.

Searching still returns Chrome, and I can start Chrome from dock anyway, but I wonder if there is a way to "Don't hide apps that are favorites"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a change with purpose. You place an application in the Dash because it is a favorite: you will use it a lot, and you will reach for it the Dash. Having it duplicated elsewhere in the Application view therefore makes less sense.

As usual, there is a Gnome Shell extension out there that can revert to the old behavior: [Favourites in AppGrid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4485/favourites-in-appgrid/) by harshadgavali.