# applications not listed in 'show application'

Tags: 22.04, .desktop, appmenu

I have re-installed my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS after struggling with some issues.

- My original installation was Ubuntu 20 (I believe 20.04), which got updated to 22.04 before this re-installation attempt.
- My `/home` is in a separate device.
- I have a 2nd (3rd considering we have also the boot) partition in the same device where the Ubuntu system is installed.

When I was re-installing it, if I got correctly, the selection I chose was to not erase/format the partition, but replace the system files. The swap file is kept as I have before at the root, in the same size, for example.

Since then, I am struggling with applications being installed but not listed in 'show applications'.

- I see several other topics asking about specific application icon being not available at 'show application' (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395877/ubuntu-21-10-show-applications-does-not-list-apps-in-dock)).
- I know we must generate our own .desktop files to have it available on the desktop or application list for cases like: appImages (and Anaconda navigator most recently, apparently).

I am struggled with the following:

- My 'show application' screen is almost empty;
- I have already installed Chrome after the re installation, I can find it if I search for it, but it is not listed.
- the `/usr/share/applications` folder have a lot of .desktop files, most of them not shown in 'show application' screen.
- I found a chrome's .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` folder. and I attempted to add a .desktop in .local/share/applications as found in several discussions as being the reference for 'show application, with no success;

So my questions are:

- Where must I put the .desktop icons to effectively have the applications listed? I want to have it listed to add as my 'favorites'.
- Considering the two folders differences and none of them being reflected in 'show application' list, it sounds like I messed up here in some configuration. How can I correct it? Or if I attempt to re-install Ubuntu how must I do it in order to not have this issue again?

---

### Update:

I realized something I believe can be relevant: When I made the re-installation, the home device got unmounted, and a full `/home` directory was generated. I am starting to believe the problem is related to it.

1. I mounted the device using the Ubuntu's disk application.
2. I re-mounted the device  in `/home`, even with other folders there… just ignoring.
3. After mounting + restart, I saw my desktop icons back. So I was happy thinking it has worked...
4. But I am starting to think it has not worked so well...  the apps not being listed I believe is an evidence of it.
5. Originally, I had an alternative user also in that device (before reinstall).
6. But after mounted, I see just my user in `/home`.
7. I see the 2nd one just when I access the device directly (not through `/home`).
8. I am unable to see any of the newly created `/home` files…
9. I suppose the Ubuntu is listing the ‘applications’ from `.desktop` files automatically generated in the newly created `/home` folder…

So my questions now are:

- Is my problem described here because I mounted my home device at `/home` directly?
- how to make Ubuntu list all applications?
- Considering the above, I believe I made something wrong in the re-install… Is it possible to set the Ubuntu must use that home device?
- How I should be done it in the order to have my ‘home device’ promptly mounted as `/home` (instead of creating new one)?
- How is the correct way to mount a ‘home device’ when Ubuntu has already a `/home` folder?

---

### Update2 - apparently the problem is not two home related

I reinstalled again Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/269892/1188532), making sure:

- the system partition is formatted (but others of that device is kept untouched).
- to have home device mounted correctly on `/home`;
- And I suppose no new `/home` beyond the used to mount the home device.

But I have still the same situation... So, it is not because I mounted a home device at `/home` after the installation created the all new home folder.

The output for `printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS` asked by @vanadium in the comments continues the same:

> /usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop

I have checked the output paths, specifically the corresponding "applications" folder inside them, when it is present. No one appear to reflect the applications listed...
Would be the idea to copy-paste the corresponding `.desktop` files  there? in "applications" inside them?

---

I am sorry if I am using the wrong terms. I am not an advanced user.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What is your output of `printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS`? You got the knowledge right - there must be a problem with your configuration. Eventually try how it works in a temporarily created fresh account.

Comment: @vanadium thank you for looking at my question. The output for  `printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS` is `/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop`.

Comment: @vanadium, I realized one thing I believe can be relevant: When I made the re-install, the home device got unmounted, and a full new  `/home` directory was generated. I re-mounted the device any way in `/home`. After mounting + restart, I saw my desktop icons back. So I was happy thinking it has worked... But I am starting to think it has not worked so well...  I am updating the question to include this details... can you please take a look and tell me any tip you have, please?